# Where I can find nhs.itk.hl7v3 library

Tags: c#, hl7-v3

I should to create a simple program to create a CDA document. So I have find this code:
[Code](https://gist.github.com/cdaapi/4951449)

Now, I have download the source code then I have compile it, but Visual Studio, don't find the

```
using nhs.itk.hl7v3.cda;
```

and other class. 
Where I can find this dll ???

Answer (score 1):

You can download the dlls from [ITK Soap Framework C#.NET](http://developer.nhs.uk/downloads-data/net-itk-soap-framework/)

> A set of C# .NET classes which provide an ITK compliant SOAP handler.
>   The release note within the bundle provides detail of the dependencies
>   on other libraries, also included within the download.

Also check [ITK Payloads – HL7v3 and CDA](http://developer.nhs.uk/library/interoperability/itk-payloads-hl7v3-and-cda/)

Comment: I have find the second link, I think that the last link is good, but I can't find the .exe file or .dll library to downalod for c#